# Pandas -- get dates closest to nth day of month

Tags: pandas, dataframe, date

This Python code identifies the rows where the day of the month equals 5. For a month that does not have day 5, because it is a weekend or holiday, I want the mask to be True for the earlier date that is closest to day 5. I could write a loop to identify such dates, but is there an array formula to do this?

```
import pandas as pd
infile = "dates.csv"
df = pd.read_csv(infile)
dtimes = pd.to_datetime(df.iloc[:,0])
mask = (dtimes.dt.day == 5)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For test purpose I created the following DataFrame (with a single column):

```
           xxx
0   2022-11-03
1   2022-11-04
2   2022-11-07
3   2022-12-02
4   2022-12-05
5   2022-12-06
6   2023-01-04
7   2023-01-05
8   2023-01-06
9   2023-02-02
10  2023-02-03
11  2023-02-06
12  2023-02-07
13  2023-04-02
14  2023-04-05
15  2023-04-06
```

Because I based my solution on *groupby* method, I created *dtimes*
as a *Series* with the index equal to values:

```
wrk = pd.to_datetime(df.iloc[:,0])
dtimes = pd.Series(wrk.values, index=wrk)
```

Then, to find the valid date within the current group of dates
(a single month), I defined the followig function:

```
def findDate(grp):
    if grp.size == 0:
        return None
    dd = grp.dt.day
    if dd.eq(5).any():
        dd = dd[dd.eq(5)]
    else:
        dd = dd[dd.lt(5)]
    return dd.index[-1]
```

To find valid dates, for "existing" months, run:

```
validDates = dtimes.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='M')).apply(findDate).dropna()
```

The result is:

```
xxx
2022-11-30   2022-11-04
2022-12-31   2022-12-05
2023-01-31   2023-01-05
2023-02-28   2023-02-03
2023-04-30   2023-04-05
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

And to create your mask, run:

```
mask = dtimes.isin(validDates).values
```

To see the filtered rows, run:

```
df[mask]
```

getting:

```
           xxx
1   2022-11-04
4   2022-12-05
7   2023-01-05
10  2023-02-03
14  2023-04-05
```